# How to get contact list from device in ios swift?

Tags: swift

I have tried to get the contact list from device but something went wrong so I did not get the contact list.

This is my code what am I doing wrong?

```
let addressBook = APAddressBook()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.registerCellClass(AddressTableViewCell.self, forModelClass: APContact.self)
    self.addressBook.fieldsMask = APContactField.Default | APContactField.Thumbnail
    self.addressBook.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)]
    self.addressBook.filterBlock = {(contact: APContact!) -> Bool in
        return contact.phones.count > 0
    }
    self.addressBook.loadContacts({ (contacts: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
            if (contacts != nil) {
                self.memoryStorage().addItems(contacts)
            } else if (error != nil) {
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            }
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're hitting the `addItems` line, but that you're not seeing it reflected in the table view? If that's the case, the issue is likely that `loadContacts` runs asynchronously, so you have to call `reloadData` on your table view when it's done. Otherwise your table view will never get updated after `APAddressBook` finishes loading the contacts.